# How do I connect my Fujitsu ScanSnap iX1500 to my computer?

Tags: drivers

I have buy a scanner from fujitsu, but the cd driver of out from me. How do to install the programs?

Answer (score 4):

Try go to official **Fujitsu** site and download driver for your device and Ubuntu version: https://www.fujitsu.com/global/support/products/computing/peripheral/scanners/sp/software/ubuntu.html

There are 2 links

1. [Download] icon-download Image Scanner Driver for Linux icon-pdf
2. Image Scanner Driver for Linux User's Guide.pdf

If you go driver link, you must set cherckbox on next page for **I agree to the end-user license agreement above.**
Then click <kbd>Download</kbd> button for **For 64-bit OS** or **For 32-bit OS** according to your Ubuntu release.

Comment: The linked page is outdated.

Answer (score 0):

Look no further.
Sane currently supports quite well this model with a lot of its features. I've used "Document Scanner", "gscan2PDF" and "Xsane".
I have currently installed version: 1.0.14-15 on Debian.